# Intent passing variable malfunction

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-intent

In my app I am trying to provide two functions to the users. One is uploading a post with an image and the other is to upload post without an image. To do so I created Strings nonselected_image and selected_image (or selected_bitmap). In case of pressing one of the TextViews by user one of the strings will be passed within the intent consequently. It works great when user wishes to create non photo post but when he wants to create one with a photo there are two posts emerging, one with photo and the other without. What did I wrong? Here is my code.

Sending an intent and strings to the next activity

```
   TextView nextScreen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNext);
        nextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to the final share screen.");

                if (isRootTask()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.return_to_fragment), getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }

            }
        });

       noPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick (View v) {

                mSelectedImage = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.nonselected_image), nonSelectedImage);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

receiving an intent and taking actions accordingly to passed variable

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to the final share screen.");
                //upload the image to firebase
        //        Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload new photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String caption = mCaption.getText().toString();

                if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
                    imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload a normal photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, imgUrl,null);
                }
                else if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap))){
                    bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.selected_bitmap));
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload a new bitmap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mFirebaseMethods.uploadNewPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, null,bitmap);
                }
                else if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.nonselected_image)));{
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this, "Attempting to upload new photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.nonselected_image));
                  mFirebaseMethods.uploadNoPhoto(getString(R.string.new_photo), caption, imageCount, imgUrl, null); // HERE IS THE ERROR

                }
```

Comment: Is there any error in the logcat?

Comment: Not a single error, just misbehaving

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Or do you still need help?

Comment: No I got it mate